# Is it possible to set the limit when pull the data from HP ALM

Tags: talend, alm

I'm trying to pull the data from HP ALM using Talend Big Data with help of tRESTClient. It is working fine. I have 100000 data in ALM, But HP ALM allowing to pull data max. of 6000 data.

How can i pull all the records from ALM? Is it possible to set the limit in any of the component?

Comment: Does your API support paging ?

Comment: You mean page-size? If yes, it is supporting in my API.

Comment: So can't you use that in order to paginate your results ?